# Automate SSH without using public key authentication or expect(1)

Tags: authentication, scripting, ssh, passwords, expect

Is there a way to pass a password to ssh automatically. I would like to automatically ssh to a server **without** using public key authentication or expect scripts, by somehow getting ssh to read the password from stdin or a file.

The reason it has to be that way is that I would like to backup my files to a server using rsync/ssh running as a cron job. This server mounts my home directory *after* it authenticates me, so using public key authentication does not work since ~/.ssh isn't available until after the login is successful. expect(1) is out of the question because I would like to run it as a cron job, and since cron jobs don't run under a terminal the combination of expect/ssh just doesn't work. I do not have root access to that server, and it would be difficult to get the admins to make any changes to the way things work there.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571741/how-to-pass-a-passphrase-to-ssh-add-without-triggering-a-prompt has a few solutions, too.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password has an answer which shows how to do this with `sshpass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sshpass`.

For example, when password is in `password.txt` file:

```
sshpass -fpassword.txt ssh username@hostname
```

(taken from the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13298487/441652))

Answer (score 7):

> expect is out of the question because I would like to run it as a cron job,
>   and since cron jobs don't run under a terminal the combination of expect/ssh
>   just doesn't work

You can run expect scripts from cron, at least you can with expect libraries like "pexpect" for Python. I just tested this to confirm, running a pexpect scp/ssh script from cron and I was able to successfully scp a file from a Python script running in cron.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pexpect

FILE="/path/to/file"
REMOTE_FILE=""
USER="user"
HOST="example.com"
PASS="mypass"
COMMAND="scp -oPubKeyAuthentication=no %s %s@%s:%s" % (FILE, USER, HOST, REMOTE_FILE)

child = pexpect.spawn(COMMAND)
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(PASS)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print child.before
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found a good tutorial on pexpect at

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/346/python-how-to-access-ssh-with-pexpect/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing your password use a public/private key system.  Add the public key for a machine to the authorized keys list on all the machines you want to connect to. Using this method SSH can validate the keys automatically and no password is required.

You can find instructions here: http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Since I just read the question more carefully, you might want to look around for a different SSH client that supports password authentication without user interaction.  I quick google search hinted that they exist (http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2004-12/0134.html)

*Related Stackoverflow questions:*

- [How do I setup Public-Key Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication)
- [Provide password using Shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224712/provide-password-using-shell-script)
- [How can I automate running commands remotely over SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243750/how-can-i-automate-running-commands-remotely-over-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

This discussion talks about what you are trying to do:

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2004-02/msg01449.html

If you can't have the admin create a local directory for you, then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

SSH requires a "leap of faith" to secure the initial handshake against future tampering.  (You initially trust the key the server gives you)

One currently avaliable but not well known approach is to use SSH-SRP.  This uses mutual password knowledge to both authenticate you and provide session encryption keys necessary to securely encrypt your ssh session.

Its MUCH more secure than SSH's initial "trust me" and does not require long term storage of keys.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use expect, pexpect or the like to feed in a password. If you do that, your password has to be somewhere in plaintext, which can actually be *less* secure than using a passwordless public/private key pair. And it's more work!

Read this page from "SSH: The Definitive Guide" for a discussion of your options:
http://www.snailbook.com/faq/no-passphrase.auto.html

Answer (score -2):

You have misunderstood how public key authentication works.  You don't need access to your remote home directory, simply put the local public key in the remote `authorized_keys` file.  Have a google around, there's plenty of guides.

Comment: The remote file system doesn't have his directory mounted until after his session starts. So `authorized_keys` won't be found.

Comment: There has to be a user somewhere doing the mounting.  Even if it's root, public key authentication is safer than having your login password lying around.