# two scp and ssh processes with single authentication

Tags: shell, ssh, scp

I need to scp and then ssh to the same host. Is it possible to authenticate just one time? Is it possible to input password once, then scp file, then ssh on that host and work interactively?

**Update**

I get HOSTNAME and SSH_PASSWORD. I never log in on that machine before. I need to send some files (probably using scp) and then log in using ssh and work on that HOST interactively. I want to save time and input password just once. I have lots of such hosts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

$ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(host => '...', user => '...', password => '...');
$ssh->scp_put('/local/path/to/file', '/remote/path/to/file');
$ssh->system();
```

Comment: This is really short solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to achieve this:

**1 - The *proper* way:**

- First, [set up ssh keys](http://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh).
- Then you can [use scp with your ssh keys.](https://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and)

**2 - Doing it with [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/):**

- Here's [an example of how to ssh with expect and have it supply the password for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298487/bash-script-to-ssh-into-a-machine-without-prompting-password-and-without-using-k/).

**3 - Use [pscp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp) instead of scp:**

- [pscp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp) is part of "putty-tools": `sudo apt-get install putty-tools`
- pscp allows you to supply the password as part of a cmdline option
- sample usage: `pscp -scp -pw $password $file_path $login@$IP:$dest_dir`

Comment: 1st way: I need to scp file to HOST and then ssh on that HOST, but I never was there before. First time log in. No

Comment: 2nd and 3rd way maybe will be useful for me. Thanks! I wish only I can avoid double starting connection. scp and ssh command open encrypted tunnel and it takes time... they are opening exactly the same tunnel, with same passwords. I wish we can reuse this that tunnel.

Comment: continuation of first comment: No keys exchanged. No knowledge about remote host, except it is linux.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an account on the remote machine, use SSH *first* to establish a connection, and then use scp to copy across wanted files - something like:

```
ssh -y joepublic@examplehost.example.com

Password: <joepublic's password>

joepublic@examplehost.example.com

scp joepublic@thathostoverthere:/home/joepublic/thefileireallywantoverhere .
```

Comment: Last command scp requires password too. I need to type password just once. And I have just remote HOSTNAME/IP, not route back.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using publickey authentication, just set up `ssh-agent`. If not `openssh` has the ability to create a master connection which further connections can then use without additional authentication, but that's not common to all `ssh` implementations. I haven't played with it much, as it's a bit of a hassle for interactive use, but it might be worth looking into for scripted use.

Comment: No publickkey authentication, just password. It need to work with remote hosts which I never was login before. No ssh-agent possible in my cases.