# "No such file or directory" error while executing shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am executing the below 
                        `#!/bin/bash`

```
###############################################################################
# This script can copy any file from Present machine to machine with IP as Test_ip and execute it :)  #
###############################################################################

############################ Main code starts here ####################################
Test_ip="10.20.12.206"

home=`pwd`
expect -c "
   spawn ssh root@$Test_ip \"mkdir /test_machine\"
   expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
   expect password { send gaur\r; exp_continue }
   exit
        "
 expect -c "
   spawn scp $home/run_check_node.sh $home/script_3.sh $home/script_2.sh  root@$Test_ip:/test_machine/
   expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
   expect password { send gaur\r; exp_continue }
   exit
        "       

expect -c "
    spawn ssh root@$Test_ip \"chmod +x /test_machine/run_check_node.sh /test_machine/script_2.sh /test_machine/script_3.sh;\"
    expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
    expect password { send gaur\r; exp_continue }
    exit
        "

expect -c "
    spawn ssh root@$Test_ip \". /test_machine/script_2.sh\"
    expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
    expect password { send gaur\r; exp_continue }
    exit
        "
```

The script shown is `script_1.sh`.
In the above code, I am creating a directory on `Test_ip` and then copying all 3 files ( `script_2.sh`, `script_3.sh` and `run_check_node.sh`) from current machine to other machine (`Test_ip`) using `scp`. Then I gave execute permission to them. When I am trying to do `spawn ssh root@$Test_ip \". /test_machine/script_2.sh\"`, it is accepting password and then displaying `"/test_machine/script_2.sh: No such file or directory"`.

I am not getting why it is telling like that. It just made all of them executable and at next command, claiming that the file does not exist!

Comment: it looks as though you copy the file to $home/script_2.sh but try and execute it from /test_machine/script_2.sh?

Comment: for scp, i am copying files from `pwd` to `test_machine` directory on other machine. So, nothing seems like what you are thinking.

Comment: The working of scp command is: scp files_to_copy where_to_copy

Comment: oh yes, sorry, my mistake

Comment: There is more relevant information in this page [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298487/bash-script-to-ssh-into-a-machine-without-prompting-password-and-without-using-k] That may be worth a look as well.

Comment: Well when you log in to those machines have those files actually been created?  Perhaps the copy failed ... I don't know expect but it doesn't look to me like you check the error code returned.  So if the previous command failed you just keep going.

Comment: @dave The files are there. That why I told that "I am not getting why it is telling like that. It just made all of them executable and at next command, claiming that the file does not exist!"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 
`expect -c "
    spawn ssh root@$Test_ip \". /test_machine/script_2.sh\"
    expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
    expect password { send gaur\r; exp_continue }
    exit
        "`

use

`expect -c "
    spawn ssh root@$Test_ip \"***bash*** /test_machine/script_2.sh\"
    expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
    expect password { send gaur\r; exp_continue }
    exit
        "`

Note: The `.` is replaced with `bash` above.
What I feel happening is, although the script `script_2.sh` is made executable, when trying to execute it from local machine to remote machine, because of using `#!/bin/bash`, it may not be allowing it to run as a shell script (by using . /file_path).
See [the difference between using bash and sh clearly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)