# Connecting through ssh with out password prompt in shell script with password defined in script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I created a shell script which which uses ssh and it connects to many servers, I wanted my script to save the password of the servers in my script itself and connect to the servers automatically without any prompts, I am not concerned of security as of now.

I tried ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=Mypassword      username@hostname

Its throwing an error Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,pubkey, password,keyboard-interactive)

I am using sun solaris UNIX server, I don't have privilege to install keygen or any changes in ssh files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're saying that you don't even have privileges over `~/.ssh` folder on the remote machine? It's very unsecure to automate ssh login with passwords. Well, ssh with passwords is kind of unsecure, to begin with.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password. See the second answer, the one with `sshpass`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate SSH without using public key authentication or expect(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271090/automate-ssh-without-using-public-key-authentication-or-expect1)