# sesu - handle password in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

sesu command prompt me to enter password..  I want to pass the password to shell script and login in my shell script.. Is it any better way to do this in shell script?

```
-bash-3.2$ sesu someusername
Please enter your password:
```

Comment: Is this works ? `(sleep 1; echo passwd ) | sesu username` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply... it doesn't work..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Provide password using Shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224712/provide-password-using-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work

```sh
echo password | sesu someusername
```

Comment: No.. it is not.. any other idea?